# Union leads to error converting from varchar to numeric

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I'm creating a new table C as a union of two tables A and B.  A column called result (numeric (18,5)) is causing problems in C.

Table C is declared first with explicit data types.

Result draws from varchar columns in A and B. I have used `try_cast` in both A and B to make sure nothing slips through.

So when I select from (A U B), I get:

> Msg 8114 (error converting data type varchar to numeric)

but when I select from only A or only B (all there just commented out) the data loads fine.

This is happening even if I use cast(null as numeric).

What gives? I would really appreciate some insight.

Comment: You need to show your query -- at least.  Sample data, desired results, and the table layouts would also help.

Comment: help us help you - please share the table structures, the query you're using and the error you get

Comment: Ah sorry, first question here. I'll add some info. Thanks!